# sns plot warning with IndexError

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': np.append(np.random.choice(np.array(['a', 'b', 'c']), 10), ['d']),
    'x': np.random.normal(size = 11),
    'y': np.random.normal(size = 11),
})

sns.lmplot(x = 'x', y = 'y', col = 'col', data = df)
```

I got the following warning:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I appreciate suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from the fact that when you randomly generate `'col'`, you get some of the letters only once so then `lmplot` ends up with only one value for the plot for that col and can't produce it with only one value.

Could you try and replace the line

```
'col': np.append(np.random.choice(np.array(['a', 'b', 'c']), 10), ['d']),
```

by

```
'col': np.random.choice(np.array(['a', 'b', 'c']), 11)
```

Your code should work then. Though ideally you would want to input a fixed list of values into `'col'` as generating it randomly might use a letter only once and then you'd get the same issue you are having now.